# Remove VisualStateManager group from control

Tags: wpf, custom-controls, visualstatemanager, vsm, visualstategroup

is it possible to delete a group from VisualStateManager?

I have a CustomControl of type ToggleButton and want to use custom state groups and need to remove some default groups from the base class.

I created my own checked state in another group and the default checked can causes some problems and errors.

Does anybody has an idea what to do?

Comment: Simply create your own template for the CustomControl and use only the groups you nee.

Comment: There is a missbehavior in WPF and .NET4.0 when I want to change a background color on MouseOver and on checked. You should never set the same properties from different stategroups (CommonStates, CheckedStates). So if the ToggleButton is checked and i move with the mouse over and leave with mouse it will not longer appear as checked. I don't want to use workarounds like rectangles and set the visibility and so on. I simply want to remove the checked stategroup from the base control or move them to CommonStates.